# Add values of CHECKED CheckBoxes, SELECTED SelectBoxes and TEXT entered in TextBox by User

Tags: jquery

What i am able to do with the following JQuery is that it returns total value of all checked boxes and select boxes.

Here is my Jquery Script:(CLICK EVENT USED)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input").click(function(event) {

    var total = 0;

    $("input:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    });

    var total_text = parseInt($("#min").text(),10);

    total = total + total_text;

    if (total === 0) {
        $('#Totalcost').val('$0');
    }
    else {
        $('#Totalcost').val('$' + total);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

What the following JQuery is capable of doing is that it returns total value entered in input type text fileds:

Here is the code:(KEYPRESS EVENT USED)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input").keypress(function(event) {

    var total = 0;

    $("input:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    });

    var total_text = 0;

    /*var total_text = parseInt($("#min").val(),10);

    total = total + total_text;*/

    if (total === 0) {
        $('#Totalcost').val('$0');
    }
    else {
        $('#Totalcost').val('$' + total);
    }
});
});
```

I tried to add

```
var total_text = parseInt($("#min").val(),10);
total = total + total_text;
```

in the topmost jquery, but the problem i faced is

1. Its not considering value of input type text as integer.
2. The click event isn't working well in case of input type text.

How can i achieve the desired result please help.
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Use an input with type `number` -- save the trouble.

Comment: Thanks @tymeJV... one of the problem gets solved by your suggestion, but still i need both the keypress and click event work harmoniously to get the desired total.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle showing the problem?

Comment: @tymeJV : here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EzYeH/29/
what i want is to sum up the values of both check boxes and text box.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some changes to your function, thought this made things easier:

```
$("input").live("change keyup", function() {
    $("#Totalcost").val(function() {
        var radioVal = parseInt($(this).siblings(":radio:checked").val());
        var textVal = parseInt($("#min").val()) || 0;

        return radioVal + textVal;
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EzYeH/32/

Edit: updated to work with `keyup and change`, used `.live()` since jQ 1.7 is being used.

For jQ 1.7+

```
$("input").on("change keyup", function() {
    $("#Totalcost").val(function() {
        var radioVal = parseInt($(this).siblings(":radio:checked").val());
        var textVal = parseInt($("#min").val()) || 0;

        return radioVal + textVal;
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EzYeH/33/

Comment: I have modified it a little bit more.. for more than one radio gruop and checkboxes.. here is the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EzYeH/37/